# Get Azure AD User Last Sign-in Date

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I want to get this date on an Azure AD user using PowerShell. [image: Last sign-in date 11/4/2021]
I cannot use `Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs` because many users haven't logged in for over 30 days. I'm interested in finding users whose last login is 60-90 days ago.

Comment: Are you logging any other user activity to Application Insights maybe?   If so you could query that.

Comment: Hello, would you please elaborate what you mean by "logging user activity to Application Insights"?

Comment: For example if your users are using an App that logs in via Azure AD B2C, and the App is logging things to Application Insights, then you can query Application Insights for when the user logged in.

Comment: Well, we don't have any App Insights set up, so that won't help, unfortunately. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Maybe via GraphAPI? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#example-5-list-the-last-sign-in-time-of-users-in-a-specific-time-range
`
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?filter=signInActivity/lastSignInDateTime le 2021-07-21T00:00:00Z
`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last sign-in date of the Azure AD users through the script below by executing it in elevated powershell. You just need to provide the credentials of Global administrator of your Azure AD tenant and the below script will fetch the details of last signed-in date for all the users present in your Microsoft 365 tenant.

```
   $LiveCred = Get-Credential
   $Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange - 
     ConnectionUri https://ps.outlook.com/powershell/ -Credential $LiveCred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
   Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
      Import-PSSession $Session
    (Get-Mailbox) | Foreach {Get-MailboxStatistics $_.Identity | Select DisplayName, LastLogonTime} | Export-CSV $Home\Desktop\LastLogonDate.csv
   Remove-PSSession $Session
```

Please find its output below: -

[image: Powershell script]
[image: Script output]

In this way, you can retrieve the last sign-in details of any Azure AD user in your tenant. You just must ensure that the user has an Office 365 license and uses mail for communication. Please find the link below for more details on the script: -

https://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/2290-last-log-in-time-and-date-powershell-script-for-office-365-to-desktop-csv-file

Comment: As per the comments in the linked thread "This script shows the last time a mailbox was polled by 365 - not when the user last logged in. I have disabled users with no access but with active mailboxes that are showing in the output. I think something may have changed in 365 since written."

Comment: Hello, @kartik. Thank you for your suggestion. The mailbox statistic "LastUserActionTime" was usually very close to the datetime in AzureAD, but not always.  Also, the LastLogonTime was never consistent with the datetime in AzureAD. I'm still confused/concerned: if the Azure AD portal can show me this date, why can't I tap into it with PowerShell (or MS Graph API)?

Comment: Azure AD can surely show you the required users' last signin date but for that purpose, 'AzureADAuditSigninLogs' will have to be used and enabled and then queried accordingly through powershell or graph API.

Comment: Hello, @KartikBhiwapurkar-MT, and thanks, but as I said in the beginning, I cannot use "Get-AzureADAuditSigninLogs" for users whose last sign-in date is further than 30 days ago.  My business requirement is 60-90 days.

Comment: Maybe you can use the script mentioned here: https://thesysadminchannel.com/get-last-logon-date-for-all-users-in-your-domain/

Comment: Regarding the script at thesysadminchannel.com, that's for lastlogondate in Active Directory, which is not the same as Azure AD. Particularly if it's a cloud-only user.

Answer (score 0):

This may have been true, but not at the moment.  I was reconciling accounts, and ran this but it made no sense, as I knew the accounts were inactive.  It returned a recent login value that did not match login logs. LastUserInteraction, was much closer to the truth but not perfect either.  E.G. When I check Azure User Profile, it shows Last sign-in date but this does not match either LastLogin or LastUserIneraction

Comment: This appears to be a comment on the previous answer, and not an answer to the original question—and, yet, it was posted as one.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31397427)

Answer (score 0):

[**How to detect and investigate inactive user accounts**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/monitoring-health/howto-manage-inactive-user-accounts) has a few examples on how you can filter on `signInActivity/lastSignInDateTime`, using [`Get-MgUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.users/get-mguser?view=graph-powershell-1.0) to find users whose last sign-in is **above or equal to (`ge`)** or **below or equal to (`le`)** 90 days ago the code would be:

```bash
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes 'User.Read.All', 'AuditLog.Read.All'

$date = [datetime]::UtcNow.AddDays(-90).ToString('s') + 'Z'
# change to ge for above or equal to 90 days
Get-MgUser -Filter "signInActivity/lastSignInDateTime le $date"
```

Note that you will also require **User.Read.All** and **AuditLog.Read.All** permissions.

Also consider the note from documentation:

[image: msdocs]